# sortBy in Spark / Scala

Tags: apache-spark

```
val p=sc.parallelize(Seq(("abc",1),("def",2),("ghi",3),("jkl",4)))
val s=p.sortBy{x=>(x._2,false)}
```

The result is coming like this:

```
(abc,1)
(jkl,4)
(def,2)
(ghi,3)
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: I am assuming you want to sort by the 2nd value in the input tuple. change the code to: `val s=p.sortBy(x=> x._2,false)`

Comment: It's clear that it executes and evaluates to true. I am curious as the reason why. At least on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

Use of {} like this leads to generation of a tuple (x._2, false) - int, boolean.

The false for descending sort, as intended, is lost.

In effect you are sorting by colX, constantY. This constantY is false. Think of SQL.

```
s=p.sortBy(x=> x._2,false)
```

is the correct syntax for, presumably, a descending sort.